# Find percentage of products against total customers

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, percentage

I have got sql table which has 2 columns userid and products, userid is unique while products will have 3 values[0,1,-1] -1 represents no products bought, 1 represents product currently
being used, while 0 represents product has been used.

What i want is a percentage query for total users in the table
product used (%): ?
products currently in use (%): ?
product not sold(%): ?

Any suggestion or assistance will be highly appreciated
Thanks

[image]
What I have tried so far?

```
Select count(userId) * 100 / (select count(products) Where products = 1) AS perc 
from product group by userid
```

Comment: That is rather simple - what have you tried so far and what error did you get?

Comment: i tried writing something like Select count(userId) * 100 / (select count(products) Where products = 1) AS perc from product group by userid , but it doesnt works

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't an adequate error description. Please be more precise.

Comment: incorrect syntax near keyword select

Comment: SQL Server does integer arithmetic.  Do you intend for the calcualtions to be integers or floating point?

Comment: need to find percentage against total , possibly float

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN products = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100   /
Count(DISTINCT Products.UserID) AS 'Currently used products%',
SUM(CASE WHEN products = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100   /
Count(DISTINCT Products.UserID) As 'Used products%',
SUM(CASE WHEN products = -1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100   /
Count(DISTINCT Products.UserID) AS 'Not sold products%'
FROM Products
```

Comment: `DISCOUNT`? I don't think that exists.

Comment: Never again using SO during a meeting... :) Thanks :)

Comment: SUM(products) will also sum -1 values

Comment: what about remaining 2 integers -1 and 0 , should i use count for it instead of sum

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Products = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100 
       / COUNT(DISTINCT UserID) AS product_currently_in_use_pct
     , SUM(CASE WHEN Products = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100 
        / COUNT(DISTINCT UserID) AS product_used_pct
     , SUM(CASE WHEN Products = -1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100 
       / COUNT(DISTINCT UserID) AS product_not_sold_pct
  FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT products,
(convert(numeric(5,2),count(products))/(SELECT convert(numeric(5,2),count(products)) FROM product)) * 100
AS "Percentage"
FROM product GROUP BY products
```

Comment: Why convert to `numeric(5,2)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this also.

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2cf0b/7)

```
select count(*) total
,count(p1.products)/count(*)*100 as currentlyused
,count(p2.products)/count(*)*100 as used
,count(p3.products)/count(*)*100 as not_sold

from products p
left join products p1 on p1.products=1 and p1.id=p.id
left join products p2 on p2.products=0 and p2.id=p.id
left join products p3 on p3.products=-1  and p3.id=p.id
```